# Excel - Entering Values Automatically into Cells/Columns upon Changing Another Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba, function, graph, charts

Cell B2 has the value for demand, Cell C2 has the value for revenue, Cell D2 has the value for cost, and Cell E2 has the value for profit. In the worksheet, there is a table (or simply put, data) that generates the values for revenue, cost, and profit for any demand between the range 1 to 40. Thus, whenever I update the value in cell B2 to any integer between 1 and 40, the values in cells C2, D2, and E2 change accordingly.

What I want to do is, create a table with columns for demand, revenue, cost and profit. I manually entered the row data for demand, that consists of integers from 1 to 40. Now, I want to have data automatically entered into the rows of other 3 columns for all matching values of demand. For example, row 1 will have demand value 1, and the corresponding values for revenue, cost, and profit (as generated by cells C2, D2, and E2 when cell B2 is 1). Is there a function or VBA I can use to enter corresponding values automatically into all the rows (1-40)? Otherwise, I have to change B2 manually and enter the corresponding values for revenue, cost and profit all manually into the table, one by one. The reason why I need the table is to generate a line chart. Thus, if there is any other idea you've got, also appreciated.

Comment: Having trouble understanding what you are trying to say, if you had an example of what you want it to look like it would be easier.  I'm thinking a DataTable could possibly do what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple solution that seems to work for you.

Use the current formulas you are using for the Revenue, Cost, and Profit within the table to calculate them.  If you aren't familiar with Excel you can enter the formulas in the first row with respect to the Demand value and drag down from the bottom right hand corner of the cell to automatically copy the formula to the below cells.

Then for your B2, C2, D2, and E2 cells you could use `VLookup` to choose the correct values from the table based on the entry in cell B2.

If you linked an image of what you are trying to do I could give exact formulas but I believe this would work for your instance.

Comment: Well said, and [here's](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db) a tutorial on how to autofill formulas